# Find out position from all bidders of an auction taking only latest submit of the vendor using mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

We have a table `bids(id,auction_id, vendor_id,bid_price,created_at)` where one vendor will have multiple bids but we take the latest using the `created_at` column

We need to find the position of the vendor from the bids of all vendors where his position is determined by the lowest bid from the same auction_id using MySQL .assumeing vendor id = 5 and auction id = 7

I have written the following query

```
SET @vendor_id := 5;
SET @auction_id := 7;

SELECT
    vendor_id,
    lowest_bid,
    FIND_IN_SET(vendor_id, sorted_vendors) AS position
FROM (
    SELECT
        b1.vendor_id,
        b1.bid_price AS lowest_bid,
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT vendor_id ORDER BY bid_price)
            FROM bids b2
            WHERE b2.auction_id = @auction_id
        ) AS sorted_vendors
    FROM bids b1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT vendor_id, MAX(created_at) AS latest_created_at
        FROM bids
        WHERE auction_id = @auction_id
        GROUP BY vendor_id
    ) latest_bids ON b1.vendor_id = latest_bids.vendor_id AND b1.created_at = latest_bids.latest_created_at
    WHERE b1.auction_id = @auction_id
) AS subquery
WHERE vendor_id = @vendor_id
ORDER BY lowest_bid
LIMIT 1;
```

But it is showing the wrong position of the vendor. Here is the DBFiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/prDKJgo5QPgwGj98544mCX/0

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it using the following query

```
SET @vendor_id := 5;
SET @auction_id := 7;

SELECT position
FROM (
    SELECT
        vendor_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY lowest_bid) AS position
    FROM (
        SELECT
            vendor_id,
            MIN(bid_price) AS lowest_bid
        FROM (
            SELECT
                vendor_id,
                bid_price,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rn
            FROM bids
            WHERE auction_id = @auction_id
        ) AS latest_bids
        WHERE rn = 1
        GROUP BY vendor_id
    ) AS vendor_bids
) AS positions
WHERE vendor_id = @vendor_id;
```

In this query, the innermost subquery latest_bids selects the latest bids from each vendor by assigning row numbers based on the descending order of created_at for each vendor. The middle subquery vendor_bids calculates the lowest bid (MIN(bid_price)) among the latest bids for each vendor and assigns positions using the ROW_NUMBER() function. Finally, the outer query filters the result to include only the position of vendor 5.

Answer (score 0):

this should give you the dataset you want which you can then filter as you need. It has bid_postn = 1 for the highest bid per auction but you can reverse this to be the lowest by changing the partition clause to use asc not desc.

```
select *
from (
    select b1.id, b1.auction_id,  b1.vendor_id,  b1.no_of_vehicle,  b1.bid_price,  b1.bid_date,   b1.active,  b1.created_by,  b1.updated_by,  b1.created_at,  b1.updated_at, row_number() over (partition by b1.auction_id order by b1.bid_price desc) bid_postn
    from bids b1
    inner join (select vendor_id, auction_id, max(created_at) created_at
                from bids
                group by vendor_id, auction_id) b2 
    on b1.vendor_id = b2.vendor_id and b1.auction_id = b2.auction_id and b1.created_at = b2.created_at

) as t1
order by auction_id, bid_postn
;
```